# Specialization of template method - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

What's wrong with this code?

```
class School {
public:
    template<typename T> size_t count() const;
private:
    vector<Boy*> boys;
    vector<Girl*> girls;
};
template<> size_t School::count<Boy>() const {
    return boys.size();
}
```

My compile says

```
error: specialization of ‘size_t School::count() [with T = Boy]’
after instantiation
```

Could you please help?

ps. This is how I'm going to use it later:

```
School s;
size_t c = s.count<Boy>();
```

Comment: Why are you using `template<typename T>` before `size_t count() const` and `template<>` before the `School::count` method?

Comment: As I understand, in first place I declare a template method, and in the second place I specialize it with one particular type

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: seem that the code works in VS2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you accidentally called `count<Boy>` in `School` *before* it is declared? One way to reproduce your error is

```
class Boy;
class Girl;

class School {
public:
    template<typename T> size_t count() const;
    size_t count_boys() const { return count<Boy>(); }
    // ^--- instantiation
private:
    std::vector<Boy*> boys;
    std::vector<Girl*> girls;
};

template<> size_t School::count<Boy>() const { return boys.size(); }
// ^--- specialization

int main () { School g; return 0; }
```

You need to move the definition of `count_boys()` after all template members are specialized.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a semi-colon.

```
class School {
public:
    template<typename T> size_t count() const;
private:
    vector<Boy*> boys;
    vector<Girl*> girls;
};                           // <-- Missing semi-colon
template<> size_t School::count<Boy>() const {
    return boys.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compilable code compiles and runs OK with g++:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Boy {};
struct Girl {};

class School {
public:
    template<typename T> size_t count() const;
private:
    vector<Boy*> boys;
    vector<Girl*> girls;
};

template<> size_t School::count<Boy>() const {
    return boys.size();
}

int main() {
    School s;
    size_t c = s.count<Boy>();
}
```

In future, please make more effort to post compilable code - in other words, code with the necessary header files and supporting classes.

Comment: Thanks for correction, next time I will more accurate. Thanks for your help as well!